# how to display image with blob image url?

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload, bonita

I have blob url for image and want to display it.
One method I tried is by using **createObjectURL()**.

```
 $scope.preview = function(path) {
        //path is 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAA....'
        var file = new Blob([ path ], {  
            type : 'image/jpeg'
        });
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file); 
        //fileURL is blob:http://localhost:8080/a8610a32-521f-407c-8f....
        console.log('fileurl: ', fileURL);
        $('img.image-preview').attr('ng-src', fileURL);

}
```

The blobl url I am getting is by **ng-file-upload 7.2.2**.

Comment: You mix angularjs call with jQuery which is not good practice. when you add `ng-src` attribute using jquery `attr()`, angularjs does not know automatically  about this DOM change.

Answer (score 0):

in case you need to get blob from url :

```
var config = { responseType: 'blob' };
$http.get(itemsUrl, config).then(function onSuccess(response) {
    var blob = response.data;
    var contentType = response.headers("content-type");
  $scope.createImageFromBlob(blob); 
});
```

but since you have that blob already

```
 $scope.preview = function(path) {
        //path is 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAA....'
        var file = new Blob([ path ], {  
            type : 'image/jpeg'
        });

        $scope.createImageFromBlob(file)

}

$scope.createImageFromBlob(blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
       let photo = reader.result;
       $scope.Imagebase64 = photo.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64','data:image/gif;base64');
    }, false);
       reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

}
```

Comment: getting errror: failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Comment: i edited the answer , you should send blob to CreateImageFromBlob function

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
$scope.preview = function(path) {
    $http.get(path)
       .then(function(response) {
           $scope.image = "data:image/jpg;base64," + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(response.data)));
           $('img.image-preview').attr('ng-src', $scope.image);
    });           
}
```